# Where can i find the code source of javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, methods

For example, i want to know how the querySelector method was built. I checked on MDN but there's only examples that show how to use it.

I also tried to check in  the console.log but nothing readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a non-standard method to do this. Please be aware that it is not fully cross-browser compatible and shouldn't be used in a production environment.

```
function hello(){
    return "Hi!";
}
console.log(hello.toSource());
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource for more.

*Edit:*
To see the source code of a built-in function, you will need to look at the engine source. This varies browser to browser. For example, Chrome uses the V8 engine. See https://github.com/v8/v8

Comment: I think the OP wants to see the source code of native javascript functions.

Comment: ... which just shows up as `function() { [native code] }`.